# How to set AWS Lambda execution for longer than 15min (fire and forget)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, execution

I have a need to create a Glue EndPoint using Lambda.

For creating 1 EndPoint it takes about 20min.
Lambda upper limit is 15min.

How to `fire & forget` lambda so that can execute creating Glue EndPoint even if it takes longer than 15min?

Thanks.

Comment: Which programming language are you writing the Lambda function in? Does the call to create the endpoint actually hang until it finishes? I think the call is going to return immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda's cannot run for longer than 15 minutes in a single execution, you can see this info [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

If you know that this operation might take longer than 15 minutes, consider using an ec2 instance with a process running on it, that way there is no timeout limitation.

Comment: I just need to kick off the process. No need to wait to finish.. What are the options there?

Comment: oh then yea for sure, just start the process and kill the Lambda. No need for the Lambda to wait for the process to finish.

Comment: My lambda got terminated automatically after 15min. During that time - it started the process of creating end point (which is taking 20min on average). After auto-kill at 15min - endpoint was not created few minutes later. That means that killing lambda - kills the process as well. Any ideas to work-around this?

Comment: The Lambda waits for the process to finish? What language is this? Typically you would handle such long processes async, by firing the request, getting a response, and then checking back later if you need to confirm the status. Please share the code

Comment: This is AWS Lambda. 15min timeout. EdgeNode was not created.

Comment: Is this written in NodeJs? Python? Java? AWS Lambda can be written in a lot of languages. It will be easier to know whats happening if you shared a code snippet, because this is not normal behavior to wait for a 15 min + operation

Comment: It is a Python but the language is not important. The point is that the process is getting terminated. Not about the language..